# How can I get rid of "|" between navbar links?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, liquid

I am not very familiar with the navbar and its properties. Here is the website: https://lvpservice.microsoftcrmportals.com/

It currently looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to remove all of the "|"s.

Comment: Did you try to... ummm.. remove them? :)

Comment: In your HTML you have `<li class="divider-vertical"></li>`. Remove them? If you can't edit the HTML, but can edit the CSS, then create a `display:none` rule for that class.

Comment: also your question should include what you actually tried. Besides it's unclear if you have access to HTML and CSS, if it is a CMS and/or dynamically generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your page, just remove the nodes: `<li class="divider-vertical"></li>`

Or if you are super lazy, just do 
`.divider-vertical {display:none!important;}`

Comment: Removing all instances of <li class="divider-vertical"></li> did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

just apply the below code you can get your o/p :

```
.divider-vertical{
  border-right: unset;
  border-left: unset;
}
```